# Mysql - ErrorException: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=6865

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, pdo

getting following error error while creating table in laravel-

Table creation syntax -

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `temp_mobile_03b1effe4c12` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `circle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `temp_mobile_03b1effe4c12_id_index` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci';

DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($sql);
```

error -

```
[2019-01-08 15:18:38] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=6865 in /var/www/html/listmanager/deploy/releases/20190107104605/app/Jobs/UpdateBulkListSubscribers.php:303
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Error while sen...', '/var/www/html/l...', 303, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/listmanager/deploy/releases/20190107104605/app/Jobs/UpdateBulkListSubscribers.php(303): PDO->exec('CREATE TABLE  t...')
#2 /var/www/html/listmanager/deploy/releases/20190107104605/app/Jobs/UpdateBulkListSubscribers.php(264): App\Jobs\UpdateBulkListSubscribers::createTempTable('temp_mobile_00d...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/listmanager/deploy/releases/20190107104605/app/Jobs/UpdateBulkListSubscribers.php(227): App\Jobs\UpdateBulkListSubscribers->updateMobileInfo()
```

Comment: have you tried to increase you max_allowed_packet of MYSQL

Comment: max_allowed_packet=524288000 currently.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel :Running A General **Statement**
Some database **statements** do not return any value. For these types of operations, you may use the statement method on the DB . Try the below syntax

```
DB::statement($sql);
```

eg:

```
DB::statement('drop table users');
```